# How to get docker-machine to work with Bastion and Private Subnet EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

My company uses a Bastion to connect to our private VPC which is where I want to create my Docker swarm. I normally connect to any EC2 instance in our vpc using my ~/.ssh/config file which redirects the ssh to our bastion host.

The problem is that docker-machine doesn't seem to have the capabilities to support this as indicated in https://github.com/docker/machine/pull/3410. Has anyone found a workaround for this or do I just use a different way to deploy swarm? Any suggestions if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

We preferred to split responsibilities of creating the environment to [terraform](http://terraform.io) since it can do much more than just instantiate the machines - like create the whole networking layer and cloud services - and then deploy the docker swarm inside it, in our case behind a bastion host as well.

The deploy overview is like this:

1. describe the cloud landscape with terraform
2. describe the initial provisioning of the machines with ansible:

   1. provision the bastion host to perform NAT/ssh/http reverse proxy to the inner hosts
   2. provision the inner hosts by installing docker, initing the swarm managers and joining the workers
3. deploy the swarm stack in the inner hosts

Not saying this is the only way, but it is what worked in our scenario. Basically skipping docker machine altogether.